# How to set a full-screen splash screen image

Tags: uwp, splash-screen

First,I think I should explain what is the splash screen. For example, the image below is the windows store splash screen:
[image: windows splash screen]

However,I think it is so samey. I wanna use a big image as the splash screen, such as:
[image: full image splash screen]

But when I set the image as the splash screen, it does not fill up the screen:
[image: small image splash screen]

I want it to be like this, the image full and centered on the screen. (I made this mock-up using Photoshop):
[image: full image splash screen]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which build are you targeting?

Comment: The Windows Store Image is just a small image centred, don't think you can do a full size image but you could do a post-splash screen with your full image maybe?

Comment: @JustinXL Both X86&ARM,but I found ARM has a bug.No matter which background color you set,it always display gray as background color.

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid I am afraid that microsoft do not let us do more wonderful things.

Comment: With FCU you can set the splash screen to be [optional](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/11/making-uwp-splash-screen-optional/). It is a declaration you make in the app manifest. Then you could display your screen as the first screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows startup screen is not fixed and it depends on the window size, which might be sometimes landscape sometimes portrait. So most of the window is expected to be filled with background color.

So what you ask for is impossible. You can only make the first page that is super simple (contains only that image) and ensure that it can appear as fast as possible and then run your setup code while that page is shown which would look like splash screen. Of course in that case you would set an empty image for the splash screen defined in Windows.

Comment: OK,maybe it is the only way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid display of the default app start screen. It consists of some image/icon centered on the one colour surface.
What can be done is to display your own start screen, but only after the default one.

You can check it here (download the sample):
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Splash-Screen-in-Universal-42c0b57a