# How can I set SpashScreen in UWP with appropriate image ratio in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, splash-screen, xamarin.uwp

I have Xamarin Application which is on Xamarin Forms based. I am facing issue in case of Windows Splash screen. I can see splash screen but image looks very smaller. I don't know where to set this image.

Currently I have set at following place with specific size:
Package.appxmenifest

[image: Kindly go through that and I attached here images]

Comment: On UWP isn't possible, read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45997867/7432494

Comment: Yeah the best option is to try to skip the splashscreen and add an extended splashscreen which can be customised more.

Comment: For some it might be good enough to simply uncheck the "Apply recommended padding" then cilck "Generate" again.  At least this was good enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default UWP splash screen will always appear unless you make it optional, in which case it will appear only when the OS takes too long to initialize the app. I have described how to make splash screen optional [on my blog](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/11/making-uwp-splash-screen-optional/).

The overall procedure is to open `Package.appxmanifest` in text editor, add the following namespace:

```
xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5
```

And then add `optional` attribute to the `SplashScreen` element:

```
<uap:SplashScreen ... uap5:Optional="true" />
```

In this manner, if the app launches fast enough, the splash screen may not display to the user and you can provide your own custom splash screen as a full-fledged Xamarin.Forms page for example. However, note that this **does not mean** you should not care about how the default UWP splash screen looks, because it is quite likely it will display anyway while the runtime is initializing, especially on low-end hardware, in which case you still should provide a user friendly graphic instead of the default image for example.